Bug in Integrate involving Sec
Integrate[2 - Sec[x], {x, 5 Pi/3, 7 Pi/3}] returns Plus[Times[Complex[Rational[4, 3], 1], Pi], Times[-1, Log[Plus[7, Times[4, Power[3, Rational[1, 2]]]]]]], but the value of the integral is real.

I believe that the Mathematica has transformed the integral, so that the contour of integration encircles a pole of the function.  I can't see a good reason why it should do so, but in general (I think) Mathematica feels free to take any path (in the complex plane) between the specified end points.

Is it possible to avoid this?

Screenshot on v 12.2.0.

I use the latest v 14.1.

It's difficult to replicate the results with NIntegrate[]. Instead of going around the pole, that path has to split a pole in half: NIntegrate[2 - Sec[x], {x, 5 Pi/3, 3 Pi/2, Pi, Pi + I, 7 Pi/3}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

Reported as a bug

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

int1 = Integrate[2 - Sec[x], {x, 5 Pi/3, 7 Pi/3}]

(* (4/3 + I) \[Pi] - Log[7 + 4 Sqrt[3]] *)

The same problem occurs with Area
int2 = Area[ImplicitRegion[0 < y < 2 - Sec[x] && 5 Pi/3 < x < 7 Pi/3, {x, y}]]

(* 1/6 ((8 + 6 I) \[Pi] - 3 Log[97 + 56 Sqrt[3]]) *)

int1 == int2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)

The workaround is to use TrigToExp
int3 = Integrate[2 - Sec[x] // TrigToExp, {x, 5 Pi/3, 7 Pi/3}]

(* (4 \[Pi])/3 - 2 Log[2 + Sqrt[3]] *)

int3 == Re[int1] // FullSimplify

(* True *)

EDIT: Reported to Wolfram Tech Support (CASE:5205937)

Without TrgiToExp Integrate[2 - Sec[x], {x, 0, Pi/3}] works fine. With TrigToExp the result is complex.

While it may appear complex, it is real. Look at Integrate[2 - Sec[x] // TrigToExp, {x, 0, Pi/3}] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

Sometimes adding a waypoint to the path of integration keeps things real:
Integrate[2 - Sec[x], {x, 5 Pi/3, 2 Pi, 7 Pi/3}]
(*  1/3 (4 \[Pi] - 3 Log[7 + 4 Sqrt[3]])  *)


Update
Some simple affine transformations yield the correct answer, too:
Integrate[(2 - Sec[x]) Dt[x, t] /. x -> 5 Pi/3 + 2 Pi/3 t, {t, 0, 1}]
% // N
(*
(4 \[Pi])/3 - 2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[3]/2]
1.55487
*)

However, some others, like x -> 2 Pi + t, fail, even though the similar one x -> 5 Pi/3 + t succeeds. Often x -> p Pi/ q +t works for integers p, q with q > 1 when in least terms; often (always?) x -> p/q + t fails. Perhaps in the successful cases, a trig identity leads Mathematica to avoid the troublesome antiderivative pointed out by @mikado.

Another path that gives the right answer: Integrate[(2 - Sec[x]) Dt[x, t] /. x -> 2 Pi - Pi/3 Exp[-Pi I t], {t, 0, 1}]

Another success: Integrate[(2 - Sec[x]) Dt[x, t] /. x -> 5 Pi/3 + 2 Pi/3 t^2, {t, 0, 1}] -- I would have thought in this case that Mma would substitute back to the original integral.

The troublesome antiderivative was pointed out by @mikado at this answer.

EDIT: I understand that other versions may give different results, so mentioning the version used
$Version
(* "14.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)


Digging into this, the problem comes down to the expression returned by Mathematica for
Integrate[Sec[x], x]
(* ArcCoth[Sin[x]] *)

Differentiating this does indeed give the expected result
D[%, x] // Simplify
(* Sec[x] *)

Substituting limits into the integral gives the results obtained for definite integrals.
 Integrate[Sec[x], {x, 5 Pi/3, 7 Pi/3}] ==
 (ArcCoth[Sin[x]] /. x -> 7 Pi/3) - (ArcCoth[Sin[x]] /. x -> 5 Pi/3)
 // FullSimplify
 (* True *)

However, this expression has the perverse effect that for real values of x, sin(x) always lies on the branch cut of ArcCoth.  Consequently, when the sign of sin(x) changes, it induces a 2 Pi I discontinuity.
I don't know if an alternative expression for the integral would avoid this problem.

Version 13 returns Integrate[Sec[x], x] == -Log[Cos[x/2] - Sin[x/2]] +    Log[Cos[x/2] + Sin[x/2]] which does not suffer the same problem in this case.

No problem in my version:
In[9]:= $Version

Out[9]= "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

In[7]:= Integrate[2 - Sec[x], {x, (5 \[Pi])/3, 2 \[Pi], (7 \[Pi])/3}]
% // N

Out[7]= (4 \[Pi])/3 + 2 Log[2 - Sqrt[3]]

Out[8]= 1.55487

